# FFT of ECG signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, frequency

This is the input signal : 
[image: original]

```
    plot(abs(fft(ecg)))
```

[image: fft]

I have also tried

```
    fvtool(x_vals)
```

which gave me :

[image: another]

However I want the x axis in Hz. So essentially I want to see the frequency spectrum of this signal in Hz.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the duration (sec) of your original signal? FFT converts sec to `1/2pi` or rad/sec units. In order to convert it to Hz you need to multiply by `2*pi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function [f amp] = getspectrum( Mdata, Mf )

%  Mdata    data 
%  Mf       sampling rate / frequency (Hz)

NFFT = 2 ^ nextpow2(length(Mdata)); 
Y = fft(double(Mdata), NFFT) / length(Mdata);
f = (double(Mf) / 2 * linspace(0, 1, NFFT / 2))'; % Vector containing frequencies in Hz
amp = 2 * abs(Y(1:(NFFT / 2))); % Vector containing corresponding amplitudes
```

I hope this might be of help.

Comment: Hi, yea when I 
        plot(f,amp)

It gives me a spectrum. Do you mind briefly explaining the code please?

Comment: "plot(f,amp)" ... that's the idea, yes.

Comment: Actually, I implemented this function a few years ago based on sample code from the matlab documentation of fft: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

Comment: This is the result that I got : 
http://s9.postimage.org/emsz22w0f/fft_main.jpg

Does it make sense? I was expecting a peak at 50 Hz but there doesnt seem to be much. THanks.

Comment: Sense: This depends on your initial sampling rate. I *guess* you have 3.6k samples in 10s, which corresponds to a sampling rate of 360 Hz. So, based on the old Nyquist's thoughts, you can "represent" signals of up to 180 Hz, meaning your plot is basically ok. The outcome depends on the mathematics behind the Fast Fourier-Transformation and your data. Well, apply e.g. a logarithm to your plot in order to see more ... but a programming Q&A website is kind of the wrong place for looking into your data. (Anyway, my money is on a peak at 60 Hz.)

Comment: Nice. What you said makes sense. Yes there is a peak at 60Hz. Why did you think so? Thanks.

Comment: The force in me. [And the last plot in your question, the result of fvtool(x_vals).]